# Opening a browser window in Thunderbird Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm currently working with a *Thunderbird Add On* which opens a pop-up every time someone hovers over a link. In this pop-up, the user should be able to **click on a link which opens a new window or tab in a browser** (one that the user set default).

```
var win = **window.open**("www.google.com", "_blank", "chrome,centerscreen");
```

Is what I tried for this, but this just opens a Thunderbird window with no address bar or anything like that, and the content in this window doesn't do anything if I click on it.

I also tried:

```
var ww = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"]
               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher);

var win = ww.**openWindow**(null, "www.google.com", "_blank", "chrome,dialog=no,all,centerscreen", null);
```

but this seems to work just the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

Even i was having the similar requirement and facing the same issue and trying to figure out the right way to do it.
Following options failed:

- Window.open
- Window.location -> location.assign()
- Components.classes mentioned in your question

After going through many many Thunderbird addon related web pages, following workaround from [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mozilla_Button_URL) worked for me:

```
messenger.launchExternalURL(url);
```